# Automorphisms of $\bf{Set}$ are naturally isomorphic to the identity

Tags: category-theory

I am trying to prove that if $F$ is an automorphism of the category $\bf{Set}$, then there is a unique natural isomorphism from the identity functor to $F$.

By Yoneda Lemma, there is a bijection between natural transformations $\mathcal{C}(A,-)\longrightarrow F$ in $[\bf{Set},\bf{Set}]$ and elements of $FA$, where $\mathcal{C}(A,-)$ is the functor sending $B$ to $\mathcal{C}(A,B)$ (set of morphisms from $A$ to $B$).

I believe that by applying Yoneda Lemma taking $A=\varnothing$, the result can be proved. However, I am quite confused because I do not know how to manage functions having domain $\varnothing$.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Do you have some further hypothesis on $F$ - say, faithfulness? Consider the functor which sends every set to $\emptyset$ and every morphism to $id_\emptyset$ ...

Comment: Ups, sorry, I will edit the question, $F$ is an automorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the result is false in general: consider the functor sending every set to $\emptyset$ and every morphism to $id_\emptyset$. So presumably you want a further condition on $F$.

---

You want two things here:

- You want $\mathcal{C}(A, -)$ to be the identity (since you're looking for a natural transformation from the identity to $F$).
- You want $FA$ to have a single element (since you want there to be exactly one natural transformation).

Taking $A=\emptyset$ fails both bulletpoints:

- For any set $X$, there is a unique map $\emptyset\rightarrow X$, namely the empty map. (In jargon: $\emptyset$ is the *initial object* in **Sets**.) So $\mathcal{C}(\emptyset, -)$ sends every set to a one-element set. That's certainly not the identity functor!
- We may well have $F\emptyset=\emptyset$. In this case, $F\emptyset$ does *not* have exactly one element.

---

So $A=\emptyset$ won't work. What will?

Well, as noted above, we need some further conditions on $F$ to make our statement true, but we can still figure out what $A$ *should* be. Both the following questions suggest a guess for $A$ (up to isomorphism, anyways):

- We want $\mathcal{C}(A, B)$ to "basically" be $B$. That is, *maps from $A$ to $B$* should be "basically" *elements of $B$*. $\emptyset$ doesn't work here, since there are too few maps from $\emptyset$ to $B$ in general. Something like $\{0, 1\}$ won't work, since in general there are too *many* maps from $\emptyset$ to $B$ (e.g. take $B=\{0, 1\}$ - $Hom(\{0, 1\}, \{0,1\})$ has four elements, not two). What sort of set should $A$ be so that maps from $A$ to $B$ correspond to individual elements of $A$?

*The "elements-as-morphisms-from-an-appropriate-object" is an important idea on its own, by the way.*

- We want $FA$ to have exactly one element. Based on that, how many elements do you think $A$ should have?

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. So I should take $A$ to be a set with exactly $1$ element, say $A=\{*\}$.

Comment: @Laura Bingo (except technically "$*$" isn't a set - the most natural choice for $A$ would be $\{\emptyset\}$, in my opinion; but this line of thinking is [evil](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principle+of+equivalence)).

Comment: $\{*\}$ is often used to indicate a singleton set in this context. The use of the "nonsense" symbol $*$ is to emphasize that the *actual* element is irrelevant. (Also, my preference would be to use a notation for the nullary product, if I was going to be specific. Something like $\{\langle\rangle\}$, but, of course, it doesn't matter.)